# mysql performance issue for large table

Tags: mysql, database-performance, large-data

You have a very large table – over 500 million records. The table is totally normalized. The table is an innodb table.  Queries are slower than acceptable even though they are optimized as much as possible.  Even though the table is already slow, it is projected that over the next 6 months it will double in size.  What things would you consider looking into to address the current performance problem and allow for a potential quadrupling for the data in the table?

I have learned that if queries are slow, the problem is coming from either processing power, RAM, Disc or number of servers. Can you tell in child language how cloud computing or load balancing or adding RAM/CPU power/Disc help increase query response time from 7 seconds to 1 second for such a large number of rows? Lets say you have X servers and Y RAM and Z Discs of C capacity which gives me S1 seconds query response time. How can you vary X,Y,Z,C to increase/decrease S1 by 1 second ?

Comment: The answer really depends on the table structure and use cases.

Comment: In case of any logging tables or any other tables where your expecting huge data day to day then its better to migrate those data to MongoDB or any other NoSQL db

Comment: @apokryfos the table structure and use cases are freezed. Channaveer Hakari the db is fixed to mysql. systems are live, we can not afford major changes.

Comment: Without any more concrete information I don't know if there's much we can say that's not pure speculation.

Comment: its a philosophical question on culture of mysql. negating the question might indicate that the person cant handle the question.

Comment: i dont mind encountering 1000 persons who cant handle this question indicated by negations, i know an expert can handle it since this is a real time problem.

Comment: While there are certainly enough experts here (including mysql developers) that could tell you a lot about optimization in general, this would literally fill books (and PowerStat mentioned one of those), which is by definition too broad for a [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): *Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.* If you can limit your question to a specific query (with all information required for performance question), we can probably tell you where to focus.

Comment: Taking your "optimized as much as possible" for granted (which, for 99% of cases that land on stackoverflow, isn't the case), 99% of those cases will profit most from faster i/o, where ram>ssd>hdd (which is only bound by how much money you want to spend). To get a number in seconds: start [profiling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/8.0/en/file-summary-tables.html), run your query and sum up. That's an approximation for the time you can save by buying enough ram to have all your data in it. If less ram is sufficient will, again, depend on your specifics.

Comment: @NN How about affording minor changes on the index or query or even a bit of schema? These combine with hardware like IO, RAM, CPU etc will make more sense.

Comment: @TomWu - Some _software_ solutions provide 10x performance improvement.  It is rare that throwing _hardware_ at a performance will gain even 2x.  Doing both may (or may not) compound.  Example:  If an index change eliminates an I/O bottleneck, then also switching to faster disks won't provide any additional speedup.

Answer (score 2):

"The table is totally normalized" -- Since there is such a thing as "over-normalization", let's see the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.

- Lots of indexes on the Fact table (the one with 500M rows) hurts `INSERT` performance.
- Continuous values (dates, datetime, numbers) should *not* be normalized.  Normalization hurts *a lot* when you need to search on a range of such values.

"I have learned that if queries are slow, the problem is coming from either processing power, RAM, Disc or number of servers." -- That's an old wives' tale.  There are usually ways to improve the indexing and/or formulation of the queries and/or the schema (as mentioned above).

Are you familiar with 'composite' indexes?

"Can you tell in child language how cloud computing or load balancing or adding RAM/CPU power/Disc help increase query response time from 7 seconds to 1 second for such a large number of rows?"  Answer:  "None of those will help."  MySQL performs one query in one CPU, and the I/O on the server is also likely to be single-threaded.  Parallelism (that you allude to) does not exist in MySQL; when it does, it is up to the user to write the code, then bemoan that it did not help as much as expected.

"then its better to migrate those data to MongoDB or any other NoSQL db" -- You are missing the point.  If you need to read 500M rows (or even 1M), it takes time.  There is no magic bullet to make I/O faster.

Sorry to be vague, but there are dozens of principles that can *significantly* speed up working with 500M rows.

A big help in Data Warehousing is "Summary Tables".  They often make things *10 times* as fast.  But they require *you* to build and maintain them.  (Again, I am being vague due to lack of specifics about your use case.)

"for 99% of cases that land on stackoverflow, isn't the case" -- Maybe only 98%.

About the only hardware fix that can give you 2x speedup is to replace a spinning drive with SSD.  CPUs have not improved by much in 18 years.  64 cores helps when you have 64 connections, but not when you timing the latency of 1 connection.  Sharding is best done when the data needed can be separated across multiple servers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest enabling the [slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html) and starting with logging queries that need longer than 5 seconds. 
Queries from the log should be performance analysed.
After this turn another round for 4,3,2,1 second.
Don't forget to switch of the log after doing this analyse.

If you are still slow, then you could think about your hardware - is it a slow san, or an ordinary harddisk, or a sd? After this you could think about your ram ... do you need more, because the system swaps all the time? Last but not least think about your cpu ... but maybe you are on a raspbery pi - which is normally slow ;-)

Comment: Thank you for good response. I am looking for relation or formula which i can use to decide numbers/sizes of RAM/disc/CPUs to have particular difference in response time for say n number of large rows. Do you know how to work that out ? Thank you.

Comment: That depends on many things - optimization is not always an exact science - it's more of a lot of experiences. Also you need to know which bolts you could turn no improve things. For example adding indexes would improve reading, but for writing indexes will slower things. So you need always to find the correct balance.

Comment: Can you give few examples so that i could understand this balance! Thank you.

Comment: You better should read a book about it - like "High Performance MySQL: Optimization, Backups, and Replication" from o'reilly.

Comment: @NN Please consider posting results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'read_%size' for first consideration and post results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_io_%' for second consideration.  The book referred to above is available on ebay for less than $5.00 and will be WORTH $500.00 to you, after deep research.